# Finding similar names in records of the same table

Tags: mysql, similarity

I need to return all entries in a table where two of the fields are similar. The following shows the table and entries. The actual code loads data from the second table but it doesn't affect this problem. I only mention it to make the example closer to the actual code.

```
    table A_table {
    id int
    wordA text
    wordB text
    }
    table B_table {
    id int
    }

    wordA = bob
    wordB = bobby

    wordA = bob
    wordB = bob

    wordA = eedddee
    wordB = ddd
```

For the above, I want the query to return all records since one record is similar to or exactly match the other.

From examples I've found here, I first tried using IN. It returned the records that were exact matches - bob and bob in this example.

```
    SELECT wordA, wordB from A_table a left join B_table b on a.id = b.id 
    where ( wordA IN wordB or wordB IN wordA )
```

I then tried variations using LIKE as shown below but no records were returned.

```
    SELECT wordA, wordB from A_table a left join B_table b on a.id = b.id 
    where ( wordA LIKE '%wordB#' or wordB LIKE '%wordA%' )

    SELECT wordA, wordB from A_table a left join B_table b on a.id = b.id 
    where ( wordA LIKE '% select wordB from B_table b2 where b2.id = a.id ) %'
```

I've read through many of the questions like this here but I couldn't find one that answered this problem. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could create a soundex column in you table and an index on this column, then in your application compute the soundex value on whichever field you want similar matches to be found when searching and store that value in the soundex column when you create or modify the record in your table.  Then compute the soundex value on search values when you query against the table's soundex column.  Some databases support soundex conversion functions

Comment: Thank you for the suggest. I just tried it using soundex(`wordA`) = soundex(`wordB`) . But that returns all similarities. So if wordA = bob and wordB = shob, that entry is returned. It should only return a field if one entry exists in the other entry wholly. This is the first time I've tried soundex so maybe I am missing some option. Is there an option that says to match the whole word?

Comment: I must not quite understand what you're trying to do, sorry.  Here is a wiki page on soundex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex  What you get using soundex is a homogenizing effect where fone, phone, and fon, are equivalent.  It isn't an exact conversion, and as the article says there are similar methods that don't produce the same outputs, but are used for the same kind of applications.  You still might need to combine  partial matches with something like soundex to get what you want.

Comment: I did some more research into soundex. One article I found said it would only work with English, which is a problem. But ignoring that for the moment, it is doing a character by character comparison. So given the names Bob and Billy, soundex will return a match because they both have b in them. What I am trying to do is a LIKE comparison - where Bob is LIKE '%Billy%' - that would return not found since Bob is not contained in Billy. Is there a way to do this sort of comparison?

Comment: I think I understand now, you want a match when you look for bob in billyboby, where bob is contained in billy bob y, right?   The problem with your use of LIKE in your original question: ( wordA LIKE '%wordB#' or wordB LIKE '%wordA%' ) is that you're actually looking for wordB or wordA rather than column's wordA and wordB.  I haven't tried this but have you tried concat( '%', wordA, '%' ) for LIKE the content of wordA and similarly for wordB?

Comment: Thank you very much for sticking with it. Your solution worked exactly how I wanted. :)